# Decomposition of a unitary representation into a sum of finite dimensional ones

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\pi$ be a unitary representation of a countable discrete group $\Gamma$ on a Hilbert space $H$. Suppose that there is a dense set $D$ of vectors in $H$ such that for every $x\in D$ the cyclic subrepresentation $\pi_x$ of $\pi$ given by $x$ contains a finite dimensional subrepresentation. Does it follow that $\pi$ is a sum of finite dimensional representations?

Notice that when we strengthen the requirement from "densely many" to "all", i.e. we require that every cyclic subrepresentation contains a finite dimensional subrepresentation, then the conclusion above follows easily by the Zorn's lemma. I am curious if "densely many" is sufficient in the requirement. But perhaps there is some counterexample.